# Is Apple allow my custom Framework used app in appstore?

Tags: ios, frameworks

I have created a payment gateway Framework having bunch of UI and web services for my client.

Now my client want this framework to be used by other IOS developer for Creating Apps and adding his payement gateway using this framework.

Will apple approve app if any app integrate my payment gateway in his/her app?

Or i have to create static library for it?

Comment: Are you asking which versions of iOS support dynamic frameworks?

Comment: Custom frameworks or static libraries are allowed. Wether or not the the app is allowed to use a payment provider is depended on what your are buying using the payment gateway. If the apps sells digital good you can only use Apple In-app purchase system. If you are selling physical goods then you **must** use a payment provide that is **not ** IAP.

Comment: my client's payment gateway is something like payUmoney is it work?
Also have u knowledge of fetching webservices inside framework or its just normal fetching like we did in apps ?

Comment: There is no difference between data communication in a library then an app. I have never heard of payUmoney, so I can not comment on this.